# How can I achieve this shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I have tried with this `superellipse_shape` package: https://pub.dev/packages/superellipse_shape

```
 class SuperellipseDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Material(
      color: Colors.blueAccent[400],
      shape: SuperellipseShape(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
      ), // SuperellipseShape
      child: Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
      ), // Container
    ); // Material

  }

}
```

But the sides has to be curved instead of the corners, is there any easier way to achieve this without custom shape?

Comment: https://github.com/Salby/superellipse_shape/blob/2750c7fa76aec328749fcfa995f3c4ddc8921b0f/lib/superellipse_shape.dart#L98

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: MyRectangle(),
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
              height: 300,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyRectangle extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    Path path = Path();
    paint.color = Colors.red;
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.4, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.29, size.height, size.width * 0.16, size.height * 0.98, size.width * 0.09, size.height * 0.97);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.06, size.height * 0.97, size.width * 0.06, size.height * 0.96, size.width * 0.05, size.height * 0.96);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.04, size.height * 0.95, size.width * 0.04, size.height * 0.94, size.width * 0.03, size.height * 0.91);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.77, 0, size.height * 0.61, 0, size.height * 0.44);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.32, size.width * 0.02, size.height / 5, size.width * 0.03, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.04, size.height * 0.07, size.width * 0.04, size.height * 0.06, size.width * 0.05, size.height * 0.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.06, size.height * 0.04, size.width * 0.07, size.height * 0.04, size.width * 0.11, size.height * 0.03);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.34, -0.01, size.width * 0.66, -0.01, size.width * 0.89, size.height * 0.03);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.94, size.height * 0.04, size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.04, size.width * 0.96, size.height * 0.05);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.96, size.height * 0.06, size.width * 0.97, size.height * 0.07, size.width * 0.97, size.height * 0.1);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.32, size.width, size.height * 0.63, size.width * 0.98, size.height * 0.86);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.97, size.height * 0.94, size.width * 0.96, size.height * 0.95, size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.96);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.92, size.height * 0.97, size.width * 0.77, size.height, size.width * 0.65, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.59, size.height, size.width * 0.46, size.height, size.width * 0.4, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.4, size.height, size.width * 0.4, size.height, size.width * 0.4, size.height);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

My Output is:

[image]

Comment: thank you, it works! but when I change the width and the height it's a bit different

Comment: Hey, how can apply on image this shape?

Comment: @MDKhali, What do you want to apply? Can you please be specific?

Comment: I want to crop or give shape to image like this red square

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, if you have SVG, then go to this site 
https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter/
and generate the shape you need.

Comment: I want canvas.drawImage, so how can i?

Answer (score 1):

Save this shape as a SVG preferably with no background. Then use this tool https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter/ to convert SVG to Flutter code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CustomPaint`

here is the doc:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create any custom designs, shapes or lines with **`Custom Paint`**. Please use the link as the reference to learn about how to do it with
[Custom Paint](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf)

Or from the flutter official doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

**Edit:**
If you don't want to do it with `Custom Paint` then all you can do it open this image in any photo editing software and remove the background of the image and use shape where you need as an image. By importing it in assets folder.